# How to Estimate Roughly The Computation Time While Using Module NetworkX

Tags: python, time-complexity, networkx, scalability

Hi I am dealing with a bit **big** (sorry for ambiguous term) graph, which has **29,981 number of nodes** with **150,000 directed-edges** in it.

I am dealing with it with module **networkx** which is fairly widely used nowadays among graph theorists.

I had executed following script early this morning in Jupyter but can't estimate when to finish:

```
import netowkx as nx
import pickle

# to read the graph
with open ('/home/zachary/H{}'.format("29981"), 'rb') as fp:
    H = pickle.load(fp)     

print(list(nx.simple_cycles(H)))
```

How can I roughly guess the time of finish of this script?

I a bit knows of what `big O` and `small O`'s.. but normally this kind of theoretically knowledge still not yet matured in my mind to industrially use those knowledge to calculate and  estimate the computation time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in [NetworkX documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html#r230), `simple_cycles` uses Johnson's algorithm to find elementary cycles. The complexity of the algorithm is `O((V+E).(1+C))` where

- `V` is the number of vertices;
- `E` is the number of edges;
- `C` the number of cycles.

In your case `V+E ~= 150,000`, so assuming the python process is not overloaded, we could expect the running time to be `150,000.K.C`.

To try to find an estimate of `K`, you can run the algorithm on smaller graphs, using power of 10 (`V+E = 10, 100, 1000 ...`) to ensure the running time of the `simple_cycles` remain proportional to `(V+E)(1+C)`, get a rough value of `K` and estimate the running time for your graph based on the number of cycles you expect to find. More precisely, if we note R(V+E,C) the actual running time for each of the experimental smaller graph, and `C0, C1, ...Cn` their respective number of cycles, then we would expect to have

```
R(100,C1)  / R(10,C0)  ~= 10.K.[(1+C1) / (1+C0)]
R(1000,C1) / R(100,C0) ~= 10.K.[(1+C2) / (1+C1)]
...
```

If the `simple_cycles` running time does not exhibit the complexity of Johnson's algorithm, then there is a non-algorithmic factor which is slowing down/preventing the computation - this would then need to be investigated.

**Follow-up**
These are the results of some investigation with the graph you provided. I tried to compute the number of cycles with the NetworkX library for smaller subgraphs and reproduced below some interesting results. There are the number of nodes and edges for each subgraph along with the number of cycles computed.

```
\#Nodes  | \#Edges | \#Cycles (computed)
----------------------------------------
   1,000 |     186 |                17
   2,000 |     675 |                37
   3,000 |   1,460 |                72
   4,000 |   2,538 |             2,147   
   4,250 |   2,881 |         2,351,883
```

I stopped at `#Nodes = 4000` for which I could not get any result within minutes.

Let's calculate, for each of these values, the value

```
log10(C)/E with C = \#Cycles and E = \#Edges.

E = \#Edges | C = \#Cycles (computed) |  log(C)/E  | 
----------------------------------------------------
        186 |                      17 |     0.0067 |
        675 |                      37 |     0.0023 |
      1,460 |                      72 |     0.0013 |
      2,538 |                   2,147 |     0,0013 |
      2,881 |               2,351,883 |     0,0022 |
```

As we can see, at least for subgraphs of `G` with less than `~2,500` edges, the number of cycles follow roughly the following power law

```
log10(C) = 0.0013.E => C = 1.003^E
```

The empirical 1.003 comes from the topology of your graph (as a side note, the [maximum theoretical number of cycles given the number of edges](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.02662) is estimated to be `1.443^E`.).

Note that we don't know if this constant remains the same as the graph gets bigger - this would be an interesting thing to check, but using a different method than this brute-force one (we already have one thousand of a billion cycle when we reach 5000 edges).

In the case (and only in this case) that the constant does not change as the graph gets bigger up to the 150,000 edges of `G`, the approximate number of cycles would be... `~10^359`

=> It seems you are actually hitting an algorithmic complexity wall. With this in mind, I don't know which alternative you wish to choose to move forward - maybe there exists non-exponential approximation algorithms?

**Note**
To experiment with subgraphs of `G` I used the following commands - specifying a target number of nodes, for instance for 3,000 nodes:

```
 H = G.copy()
 H.remove_nodes_from(list(nodes)[3000:])
 len(list(nx.simple_cycles(H)))
```

Comment: you mean `.` by multiplication given on scalars?

Comment: Yes indeed - `150,000*K*C`

Comment: I don't your final paragraph. How's your expression `If the simple_cycles running time does not exhibit the complexity of Johnson's algorithm` defined?

Comment: I really don't know how many cycles would exist.. in this graph in advance.. okay will try to estimate that point following your suggestion keep randomly increasing the size of graph

Comment: I meant - you can for instance build simple graphs for which `V+E=10`, `V+E=100` and `V+E=1000` (respectively), get the running time for each of them, and check they are proportional to `(V+E)(1+C)`, and then get an estimation of the factor `K`.

Comment: Thx for your practical guidance. 
This is the graph that I mentioned in the OP, which contains the each pages of `en.wiktionary.org/ word_name` as a node, and their `hyperlinks` contained as directed edges. If you're interested in this graphical structure, hope you can also have and share a chance to look into it. Thanks
 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/u0jhxslzrc0ceng/H29981?dl=0

Comment: Edited the answer with what I meant by this sentence

Comment: What is the type of the file in the link? I tried to open it but cannot find its type/extension (tried to unzip but it doesn't seem to be an archive)

Comment: @Alexander Dupriez  Oh sorry that is what I should have mentioned. It is pickle. You can load the data through pyhton built-in pickle module, I do that like using following script:

`import pickle  with open ('/Users/zachary/Desktop/G{}'.format("29811"), 'rb') as fp:
    G = pickle.load(fp)`

I use it a lot because it can store any python object

Comment: Added some results after investigation - the number of cycles grow exponentially, and so is the runtime since it is proportional to the number of cycles. So you are actually hitting an algorithmic complexity wall!

Comment: First of all, thank you for your deep research and I read it deeply. The reason I try to get the cycle is because, usually the words which recursively get back to "self" in a short steps of jumping is kinda "axiomatic" (I called those like this, and few of linguists use this term too. This concept might a bit unfamiliar to you, but think about basis in math. Linguists also want to find basis like object in language - such as "be", "exist", "good", "bad" - those are if you really check in graph, you can get back to "self" in a relatively small number of steps. And they "span" the network

Comment: So my final goal is about how to determine the depth of steps that worth being called as "axiomatic" in word network. Do you think the number of cycles would be not exponentially increasing if I limit the total length of cycles?

Comment: And the reason why I do this is also - because I am trying to use "graph embeddings" instead of famous Word2Vec. But to use graph embedding, I need to determine the optimal embedding size. I positively expect that the number of axiomatic words would be a good estimator for the best embedding dimension.

Comment: And the algorithm would have been much better if you took the "random nodes". because I collected them with a selenium traveller- the reason I call it traveller because it actually first visit random page as a start, then crawl every "hyperlinked word" then add them to node, then choose "randomly" one node then visit there and repeat the prior process. If networkx node list save those nodes appended order, the graph might have been a bit biased..but this if my rough guess and not sure of it.

Comment: and more funny story is, there exist ~ 1,000,000 pages in english wiktionary. And I just crawled 30,000 in a very random manner but it still too big to us. What a world of complexity! In this 5mb pickle jar, there exist a big complexity!

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uhq491s5wnkw8cq/wiktionary_hyperlink_graph_template-Copy1.ipynb?dl=0

This is a crawler that I used when collecting the provided graph. I used three of them for 3days to collect 29981 nodes with edges - then I combined those three and get it. The speed of nodes increasing at first very rapid like 3000 nodes in an hour, but keep decreasing - later on it converges to 100 nodes appended an hour on average.

Comment: Is there any provided module that limit the cycles in length with given parameters? I'd like to try this from 2, because "exist -> be -> exist" is very famous cycle (we call this recursive definition of word) in this field.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations - I will check if the results were biased by the method used to select the nodes (I assumed there were arbitrarily ordered). If I understand correctly, you would be interested in "short" cycles only? Now what would be the length of such cycles? If this number is "small enough", then a naive brute-force algorithm may provide some results - if the number of edges is uniformly spread in the graph, then a naive algorithm would have a complexity of `V.(V/E)^k` with `k` the length of the cycles looked for. So cycles as "exist" -> "be" -> "exist" would be doable.

Comment: Yes you're understanding is correct. I need to check 1) whether those "short" cycles are actually looks "axiomatic" upon human intuition- anyway the most important number for `k` is 2,3, or at most 4. They deserve to be called "small enough"  2) As I keep increasing `k`, which `word` will we sequentially face for the source of cycle? That's my second question. One thing I roughly but intuitively knows is that, small cycles normally for `predicates` - verb or adjectives and bigger cycles normally for `nouns`. That's what my intuition tells.

Comment: I re-run the cycle-finding method on sub-graphs *after* shuffling the list of nodes to remove the potential bias you suggested. The results remain roughly the same - I observed more variability in the base of the powers. The conclusions remain the same, of course. To follow-up on your last comment: if `k <= 4`, then I think a brute-force solution may be computable. I do not know about the graph libraries available in Python - it might be worth asking on SO about it? Or maybe you can try to write a brute-force algorithm in python?

Comment: Understood point 2) - so basically you will need a more comprehensive description of the cycles found by the algorithm - you could list all such cycles and categorize their source afterwards (post-processing), or alternatively categorize the nodes before finding cycles and capture these categories while you are finding cycles with the ad-hoc algorithm previously discussed.